# Kamailio, use extension to send request to user (similar to Asterisk extensions)

Tags: sip, kamailio

I am using Kamailio and have just setup everything and added two subscribers to the system. I would like to know if there is a way to send INVITE requests according to an extension variable, instead of using the subscriber's username. Thank you and have a great one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you look for is more identities for the same user, then yes, it is possible. To be clear, by this I mean to have the possibility to call *alice@sipdomain.com* using also *1001@sipdomain.com* or *manager@sipdomain.com*.

One way to do it is using *alias_db* module, which keeps a table with the association between aliases and the main SIP identity. The default *kamailio.cfg* has an option to enable such a feature, look for *WITH_ALIASDB* define.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for and it is working as expected, :D.